# Add VM to existing vnet and subnet

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-resource-manager, azure-virtual-network

I am using a json file to create a VM. Everything works good with exception of the vnet and subnet, every time I created a new VM, it creates a new vnet and subnet, how can I create VMs and assign them to an existing vnet and subnet using a json template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried below sample template

https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vm-different-rg-vnet

you should be able to update your ARM template to create your VM into an existing VNet.

Answer (score 0):

am assuming by json, you mean an ARM Template.

you should be able to do that by grabbing a subnet reference to the existing subnet on your existing VNET and then associating your new VM's NIC to the subnet reference you obtained. have a look at sample [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/201-specialized-vm-in-existing-vnet/azuredeploy.json)