# How can I add Azure VM to existing Vnet or new Vnet using ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network, azure-rm-template, azure-vm-templates

I am creating JSON file for ARM template to deploy Azure VM and its dependent resources.

I have created RHEL VM with following resources(all are newly created):-

```
Storage Account
Diagnostic Storage Account
Virtual Network
Network Interface
Public IP Address
Network Security Group
```

Now I want to create Azure VM with existing Vnet, Subnet or new Vnet, subnet. Is there any example I can follow up. How can I do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now I want to create Azure VM with existing Vnet

You could refer to this [example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vm-os-disk-and-data-disk-existing-vnet).

If you want to more templates, you could search the [templates gallery](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/templates/?resourceType=Microsoft.Resources) to discover what you need.

> or new Vnet, subnet.

You could refer to this [example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/101-vm-simple-linux), just use an existing resource group.

Comment: If I want to use both(existing Vnet and create new Vnet) in same ARM template. How can I do?

Comment: Based on my knowledge, it is not possible. You had better use two templates and use PoweShell to control the process.

Comment: Ok. Is there any example available to use both with two templates?

Comment: You could use `New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment` to execute the first template and the task execute successful. You could use `New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment` to execute the second template.

Comment: Is there a way to use with linked template in ARM?

Comment: Based on my knowledge, it is not possible.

Comment: You could check this [example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-extend-vnet-to-multi-vnet) which could create multiple VNet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139228/discussion-between-walter-msft-and-karan).

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty straightforward with Microsoft's [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-linux-cli-deploy-templates).

The challenge here usually lies with understanding the dependencies. In that example, you aren't saying I want this VM to launch in this Vnet, you are saying, "I want this VM to use this NIC which is associated with this Subnet of this Vnet"

It is easiest to just use the example provided at the bottom of that link and work your way forward. With your case, you will end up being able to simply remove the Vnet resource block and add your own Vnet's properties in.

[This is an extra tool](https://resources.azure.com/) for working with ARM templates.

Comment: This is possibly a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35167210/add-vm-to-existing-vnet-and-subnet/35214868#35214868 but was never given an accepted answer.